# Facebook token_url parameter

Tags: google-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-signin, oauth-2.0

I am using a module for Facebook login in my app using `Electron.js`. However there is a `tokenUrl` parameter that I could not find what I should put for it: 
here is the code

```
const config = {
clientId: environment.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
clientSecret: 's494df4sd6f4984984984',
authorizationUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth',
tokenUrl: '??????',
useBasicAuthorizationHeader: false,
redirectUri: "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"


};
```

the `token_url` for google works for perfect, but not for Facebook. here is the Google `token_url`:

```
 tokenUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#exchangecode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do the auth using the url as the following:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=AfterAuthURI&response_type=token"